# Object become Hashmap after Serialization and Deserialization

Tags: java, serialization, hessian

I have an object called Tree:

```
public class Tree{

   protected Node  root;

   public static class Node{
       protected Node  parent;
       protected List<Node> children;
   }
}
```

I am serializing and then deserializing it:

```
// build a tree
Tree t = Tree.build();

// serialize
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(512);
HessianOutput out = new HessianOutput(baos);
out.writeObject(t);
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();

// deserialize
ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(b);
HessianInput in = new HessianInput(inputStream);
Object obj = in.readObject(); // obj becomes HashMap
```

I need a tree object instead of a hashmap. Can anyone figure out how it comes? Thanks in advance?

Comment: Wouldn't this be web-service protocol (Hessian) dependent? What does this protocol's documentation say?

Comment: I'm asking honestly since I don't know the answer myself

Comment: I ran your example with Hessian 4.0.63 and the object deserialized is a Tree and not a HashMap.